# Can I use spring thymeleaf with layoutdialect?

Tags: spring, layout, thymeleaf, dialect

Like in topic, Can I use Thymeleaf layout dialect with spring?
Do I have to use Spring Standard Dialect?

There is so many materials on web, which makes me really confused.

I've started with Layout dialect, but I cant get to work whole app.

Here is my template main file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl" lang="pl" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    <head>
        <title>DERP></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../../css/template.css" th:href="@{/css/template.css}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../../lib/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" th:href="@{/lib/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../../lib/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/css/themes/slate/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/lib/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/css/themes/slate/bootstrap.min.css}" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../../lib/animate/animate.css" th:href="@{/lib/animate/animate.css}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:include="fragments/bodyHeader" th:remove="tag">
            for prototyping
        </div>

        <div id="mainMenu">
              <div class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  </button>
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">DERP</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Active</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-header">Dropdown header</li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Customer <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> User <b class="caret"></b></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
        <!-- #mainMenu ENDS-->
        <div layout:fragment="header">Static header</div>
        <div layout:fragment="pageContent">Demo static page content</div>
        <div id="pageFooter" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">Copyright Daniel Korbel 2014</div>
        </div>
        <div id="javaScriptSection">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" th:src="@{lib/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/template.js" th:src="@{/js/template.js}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/noty-2.3.1/js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js" th:src="@{/lib/noty-2.3.1/js/noty/packaged/jquery.noty.packaged.min.js}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/noty-2.3.1/js/noty/layouts/topRight.js" th:src="@{/lib/noty-2.3.1/js/noty/layouts/topRight.js}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/notyStarter.js" th:src="@{/js/notyStarter.js}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" th:src="@{/lib/bootstrap-3.3.1-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my sample body file which is returned by controller:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorator="layout/template">
    <div layout:fragment="pageContent">
        <p>LIST</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

But unfortunatelly this code works only with Layout dialect.

Can anyone help me transform that code to work with spring standard dialect?

My thymeleaf config:

```
public class ThymeleafConfig {

    @Bean 
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean 
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        templateEngine.setDialect(new SpringStandardDialect());
        //templateEngine.setDialect(new LayoutDialect());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean 
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding the layoutdialect to the templateengine should be enough to get it working. Don't use `setDialect`. You should have an `addDialect` or `setAdditionalDialects` method or something like that. (I use the xml config so i don't know the exact names)

UPDATE: added xml config

```
<beans:bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
    <beans:property name="templateResolvers">
        <beans:set>
            <beans:ref bean="servletContextTemplateResolver" />
            <beans:ref bean="classLoaderTemplateResolver" />
        </beans:set>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="dialects">
        <beans:set>
            <beans:ref bean="thymeleafSpringDialect" />
        </beans:set>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="additionalDialects">
        <beans:set>
            <beans:bean class="nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect" />
            <beans:bean
                class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect" />
            <beans:bean class="ch.mfrey.thymeleaf.extras.with.WithDialect" />
            <beans:bean class="ch.mfrey.thymeleaf.extras.cache.CacheDialect" />
        </beans:set>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: can You post Your xml?

Comment: It's looks like You use older library version. In my case I have to choose between LayoutDialect and SpringStandardDialect, but I am not sure of choose. For now I will try LayoutDialect(), cause of decorator mode. Hope I wont miss any spring facilities.